# IntelliJ 12 not able to create a project using Java 7 on Mac OS 10.8.3

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to create a simple Java project in IntelliJ 12 (IDEA version), using Java 7 on a Mac (Mountain Lion 10.8.3). I've not been able to do so, the project window remains unresponsive. Any ideas why?

Comment: See http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't occur anymore once I changed the JVM version in the info.plist file from 1.6* to 1.7*! See more details here:
http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956